Google Colaboratoryでactivateができず、常にCondaError: Run 'conda init' before 'conda activate'と表示されてしまう。
私は研究のために Numan をcloneして、colabで利用しようと考えています。GPUが使えるからです。
そこで次のようにコマンドを打つと、CondaError: Run 'conda init' before 'conda activate'と表示されてしまいます。
!source /usr/local/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
!conda activate neuman_env

初期化を行うために
!conda init bash

を実行してcolabのメニューからランタイムを再起動して、アクティベイトしても初期化してください、と表示されてしまいます。
どういかご助力ください。
Numanを使うためのコード一覧
#Minicondaのインストール、Condaの初期化、適切なConda環境の作成
!wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local

!conda init bash

!git clone https://github.com/apple/ml-neuman
%cd ml-neuman

★エラー
!source /usr/local/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
!conda activate neuman_env

!conda --version
>>>conda 24.5.0

!source ~/.bashrc

!conda env list
>># conda environments:
>>#
>>base                     /usr/local
>>neuman_env               /usr/local/envs/neuman_env


もしかしたら、こちらの記事を参考に何のシェルが使われているかによってinitの対象を変える必要があるのでは？ google colaboratoryでcondaコマンドを使い仮想環境をactivateする方法 ただし他の類似の記事ではそれらは記載されていませんが。Google Colabを使って最新AI論文のコードを実行するためのConda仮想環境構築ガイド, Google ColabでRDKit：ケモインフォマティクス用のpython環境を手軽に構築, Google ColaboratoryにminiforgeをインストールしてRDkitを走らせた, Google Colaboratoryにcondaをインストールしケモインフォマティクスしてみる

こちらでhttps://qiita.com/kimisyo/items/2b797c68a756c468e497解決しましたー！
